# Solving an upper triangular system of linear equations

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, asymptotics, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra

Given

$$(I+T_1T_2T_3)\,x = b$$

where $I$ is the identity matrix and $T_1$, $T_2$ and $T_3$ are invertible upper triangular matrices. Matrix $(I+T_1T_2T_3)$ is also invertible. I want to know what the *fastest* method to find vector $x$ is.

I know that it is easy to

1. Find $A = I + T_1T_2T_3$ with $\mathcal{O(n^3)}$ basic arithmetic operations.
2. Find $A^{-1}b$ with $\mathcal{O(n^2)}$ basic arithmetic operations.

As a result it needs  $\mathcal{O(n^3)}$ operations. I wonder if it is possible to do it with $\mathcal{O(n^2)}$ operations?

Note: I updated the question by adding the invertible matrix $T_3$. For case of two matrices, we can write the LHS, in form of $T_1^{-1}(T_1^{-1}+T_2)x$, which needs $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ operations to solve.

Comment: Yes, triangular matrices can be solved with lower complexity than general matrices. Start with row operations on the lower end, working your way upwards.

Comment: The lone diagonal element in lower right you can use it to make all the other along the rightmost column 0 with just one multiply+add each. And then you can do the same to the next diagonal element since the triangle has shrunk by one.

Comment: So you should get away with at most $n^2/2$ multiply-adds.

Comment: @mathreadler you are right that it is possible to find inverse of triangular matrices. But here we need to find $T_1T_2$ first, which is most of the cost for solving the equation. I edited the last line to be more clear.

Comment: Multiplication of triangular matrices are not as costy as general matrix-matrix multiplication since we can skip computing half right away and there are many 0s in the scalar products we need to compute.

Comment: @mathreadler it is a well established fact that multiplication of sparse matrices is faster. But for general triangular matrices, is it other than  $\mathcal{O(n^3)}$? If not, the main problem is still multiplying $T_1$ and $T_2$.

Comment: In your update, how is $T$defined in terms of $T_1$ and $T_2$? Also,I do not understand how you avoid the cost of forming $T_1^{-1}$? Would you please add a few words about this?

Comment: Just to be sure. Do you have a method for solving $(I+T_1T_2)x=b$ using $O(n^2)$ arithmetic operations which returns the exact solution if exact arithmetic is used? I can only do this in two special cases, i.e. $T_1 = \pm T_2$. If you have a solution of this problem, then I would dearly like to see it.

Comment: @CarlChristian, see my answer below, for the case that $T_3 = I$.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do to avoid assembling the left hand side matrix if it is the $T_1T_2$ matrix multiplication you are afraid of:

Try a Krylov subspace method like conjugate residuals. Then in each iteration you can do a series of sparse matrix-vector multiplications instead. It will be linear in number of $T_k$ matrix factors so only $n^2/2$ multiplications times something unrelated to $n$ : will still be $O(n^2)$ - for each iteration. However the number of iterations we need for convergence can in worst case be $n$, which lands us with $O(n^3)$ in worst case. But there can be a huge difference between worst case and average case. Often Krylov methods converge to a useful solution in a very small fraction of $n$.

---

Here is the number of scalar multiplications per element of the product matrix

$$\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&2&3&4\\0&1&2&3\\0&0&1&2\\0&0&0&1\end{array}\right]$$

It sums up to $20$ for this $4\times 4$ matrix compared to $4^3=64$. Given this structure how can we derive a formula for it?

Comment: I did not get the part of your argument regarding computation complexity. For a krylov subspace method, as you mentioned we need $O(n)$ iterations in the worst case. Meanwhile, for each iteration, we need to multiply matrix $T_1$ and $T_2$ times other vectors, which takes $O(n^2)$, for general triangular matrices. This again becomes $O(n^3)$, right?

Comment: yes you are right n/2 by n, $n^2/2$

Comment: So, what you say is that in order to solve the equation, we need $O(n^3)$ operations?

Comment: No I am not saying that. I am saying in worst case. There is a big difference between worst case and average case.

Comment: I edited to $n^2/2$ in my answer.

Comment: I saw your edit. I answered my original question as a note. I also updated the question to make it more complicated (since I answered the original one). I wonder if you can answer the updated one.

Comment: Don't change questions after you have gotten answers. Instead make a new one.

Comment: I checked to see it is compatible with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

This answers the question for the case that $T_3 = I,$ which was my original question and I am writing it because Carl asked me.

*Fact*: For the invertible upper triangular matrix $T_1$, we need $O(n^2)$ operations to find its inverse.

Finding $x$ is equivalent to solving the following equation:

$$(T_1^{-1}+T_2)x = T_1^{-1}b.$$
Using the fact above, computing the upper-triangular $(T_1^{-1}+T_2)$ needs $O(n^2)$ operations. Finding $T_1^{-1}b$ needs $O(n^2)$ operations as well. Since $(T_1^{-1}+T_2)$ is upper-triangular, we can find $x$  from equation above with another $n^2/2$ operations.

Comment: I agree that solving $Tx=f$ where $T$ is triangular and $n$ by $n$ requires $1+3+5+\dotsc+(2n-1) = n^2$ operations. Therefore, to invert $T$ we need $1+2^2+3^2+\dotsc+n^2 = O(n^3)$ operations because we have to solve $n$ triangular systems where the ith system has dimension $i$. Granted, the right hand sides have a special structure (mostly) zeros, but this is not enough to save one order of magnitude.

Comment: As @Carl Christian wrote, the inversion of a triangular matrix is in $O(n^3)$, more precisely, the best estimation is (I think) $n^3/3$.  In fact, we can go faster, using parallelizing.